# Error creating bean with name '_loginCommandPostProcessor'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, blazeds

I'm currently using spring-flex integration and want to add webservices that are secured through spring as well.

To that end I am trying to create two http tags?

spring-security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.somenamespace.login" />   
     <context:annotation-config/>

     <beans:bean id="entryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.flex.security4.FlexAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>


    <http entry-point-ref="entryPoint" pattern="/messagebroker/**">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated"/>
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
    </http>

    <http  pattern="*">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated"/>
        <http-basic />
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class=
"org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />

    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />

    <beans:bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/admin/impersonate"/>
        <beans:property name="targetUrl" value="/cre/CRE.html"/>
        <beans:property name="switchFailureUrl" value="/admin/switchUser"/>
    </beans:bean> 


    <beans:bean id="defaultMessageTemplate" class="org.springframework.flex.messaging.MessageTemplate" />

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.somenamespace.login.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>  <    
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name '_loginCommandPostProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sessionAuthenticationStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#1,sas
```

Comment: It is getting clear from the error, that you have 2 beans initialized in your spring context apart from `sas`. Are you sure you are not scanning `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session`? It could be declared in other xml files.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means.  How do I make sure I'm not scanning it?

Comment: I've post my reply to your question as an answer below with possible solutions, please, look.

Comment: did you find the solution ? I'm also getting this with 4.2.4.RELEASE version of spring-security. But in my case, I have set session-fixation to none. I'm still getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.somenamespace.login" />` -- by this you are telling Spring: "Please, scan `com.somenamespace.login` and initialize any beans marked with annotations: `@Component`,  `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Controller` into my application context".

So, you have 3 beans initialized into the context which are candidates to be autowired into property `sessionAuthenticationStrategy`:

1. `sas` -- initialized by scanning `com.somenamespace.login` (see the
   declaration at the beginning of this answer).
2. `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0`
   -- the bean you didn't expect to be initialized; probably you may have another one  in other xml spring
   context files (if they exist in your application -- I don't know
   that).
3. `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#1`- see point 2.

Spring doesn't know which one to choose. Thus you are getting the error.

I may suggest you two possible solutions:

1. The dirty one, but fast. You mark your `sas` bean as a primary. Like this:
   `<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" primary=true/>` Please, also be  advised, that if you need to inject bean of `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` class or any other bean which implements `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` somewhere in your application, but not `sas`, this solution won't suit you, as it will always inject `sas`.
2. More cleaner solution, but may require more time: find out what can
   provoke the unexpected beans to be initiliazed and fix it. From my point of
   view, as I said, it could be additional `<context:component-scan />`
   declaration somewhere in your spring context xml files (if there are
   more than one).

   Good luck! I hope this could help.